# BOOT problems with ubuntu on hp pavilion g series laptop.

Tags: boot

I have installed ubuntu 15.4 on HP pavilion g series laptop. with A6 AMD processor. 
The problem is the system doesn't boot. I have to do trial and error many times and then the boot works. 
Thanks in advance
kind regards
Suchitra

Comment: What happens when it doesn't boot? Does the screen turn on? Do you see the BIOS/EFI, booloader, OS startup? If absolutely nothing happens and boot works randomly your start button is broken.

Comment: Hi The screen turns on and we see the first screen in magenta color displaying ubuntu there after it turns black and hangs unless we restart it.

Comment: Try changing the light settings FN + F3. This is not a permanent fix. I solve it by installing the proprietary driver but I'm not happy with it.